# Reading and writing server-side data

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django website to run a user study, with a series of questions for the user. At the beginning of each user study, a large amount of data is created on the server. This data is then used throughout the study to determine which question to show to the user. The data is unique for each user, and changes each time the user answers a question. The data is around 1GB.

What is the best way to implement this? Should this be done with user sessions? Or should I store it in the database? Or another solution?

Comment: Yes, each user requires the use of a large amount of data during their session. It may well be significantly less than 1GB in fact, but I just wanted to show that it will be large. Is there any reason why this could not be stored as a session variable?

Comment: 1GB/user is huge. Could you generate the data by chunks, only when needed for the next question ? And thow it away afterward ? Could you compress it ? You are likely asking the wrong question.

Comment: Why should it matter how large this memory requirement is? I'm assuming that passing it as a session variable only passes a pointer / reference to the data, not the actual data itself. So apart from the requirement on the server to store 1GB per user, why should this be an issue for Django?

Comment: You're not taking into account the fact that websites are multi-user environments and Django is usually served by a multi-process server. That means that each process will need to keep in memory all the data for each user currently active, which could be many many GB.